# Don't Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core support memory database?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Don't Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core support memory database?

Below code get NullReferenceException

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public IEnumerable<dynamic> Index()
    {
        using(var cn = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=:memory:;")){
            return cn.Query(@"select 1 id,'1' val union select 2 , '2'");
        }
    }
```

csproj :

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="2.0.35" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Details :

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection.Open()
   at DB.GetConnection() in C:\Users\HanYang\Downloads\New folder (4)\demo\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 28
   at HomeController.Index() in C:\Users\HanYang\Downloads\New folder (4)\demo\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 17
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

P.S :
System.Data.SQLite.Core can work.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the [correct SQLitePCLRaw package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/custom-versions)? Is there a reason you're not using `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`?

Comment: Is it significant that your screenshot has a space between `Data` and `Source` ? All my connectionstrings look like `Data Source=` but I've no idea if `DataSource=` is supported or not.. On SQLServer database driver, not suing a space produces "Keyword not supported: datasource" but on SQLite driver, I'm not sure what the behavior is

Comment: Good spot: [it should have a space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/connection-strings#in-memory)

Comment: @canton7  could u answer below? it slove my problem!

Comment: Heh, this is what happens when we're not sure *what* solved your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice you're using `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` rather than the normal `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite`.

`Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` exists so that you can use a custom version of the native SQLite library, [see these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/custom-versions). Make sure that you're using an appropriate `SQLitePCLRaw` package, or use the more normal `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` package.